# Ffmpeg how merge or blend two images into one

Tags: ffmpeg, merge, combine, blend

I have two images which I created using FFMPEG command REMAP. I wish to combine the two images to form a new rearranged image. I am lost and dumbfounded by MERGE or BLEND or CONSENTRATE.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can take a look on hudin, which is exactly for stitching panoramas: https://hugin.sourceforge.io/

Answer (score 1):

Solving my own question.
I seem to have started on the complicated track.
Here is the simple solution using command CROP.

```
FOR %%G IN (360_????.jpg) DO (

REM Crop image 5792x2896 to smaller size 1448:2896 at X,Y of 4344:0
ffmpeg -i %%G -vf  "crop=1448:2896:4344:0" -c:a copy -y 1crop.jpg

REM Crop image 5792x2896 to smaller size 4344:2896 at X,Y of 0:0
ffmpeg -i %%G -vf  "crop=4344:2896:0:0" -c:a copy -y 2crop.jpg

REM Haystack side by side one image to the second image
ffmpeg -i 1crop.jpg -i 2crop.jpg -filter_complex hstack -q:v 1 -y new%%G.jpg

REM Delete temporary files
del 1crop.jpg
del 2crop.jpg
```